# swapping tokens on clipper dex with code

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange, arbitrage

https://etherscan.io/address/0x655eDCE464CC797526600a462A8154650EEe4B77 This is the link to the Clipper exchange pool where you can swap weth/wbtc/usdt/usdc/dai. I've been trying to execute a swap with it with code, but weirdly i can't find one person even mentioning the code anywhere.

The swap parameters requires a signature like this:
`function swap(address inputToken, address outputToken, uint256 inputAmount, uint256 outputAmount, uint256 goodUntil, address destinationAddress, Signature calldata theSignature, bytes calldata auxiliaryData) public override marketIsRunning`
The signature struct look like this   `struct Signature {uint8 v; bytes32 r; bytes32 s;}`. The signature struct and other functions related to the signature are on the file File 20 of 22 : ClipperCommonExchange.sol. I think the signature is either to check that you are whitelisted, or it's to verify and lock in the swap amounts before the execution (I think Clipper works this way).

What does the Signature do, and how can I get it off chain, so I can use this swap function in a smart contract and pass the signature. Also is it possible to get quotes with Clipper with some smart contract?

Comment: A good answer to this is gonna probably need a couple of hours, so props to anyone who can take the time. To investigate yourself look up eip712 and how to sign typed data for off chain approvals. They are using for permits, with v, r and s being used to recover signer on chain. Can look at an xSwap example for an idea of what you need to produce at a lower level. Your lang/lib might have helper functions to make it easier: https://github.com/0xMaka/w3py/blob/main/xSwap.py#L50